# Coupling of supergravity to matter

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, supersymmetry, supergravity

Whereas the "derivation" of the pure supergravity Lagrangian seems to be rather straightforward, once it comes to combine supergravity with matter, i.e. for instance with an ungauged chiral super-multiplet, it seems to have almost no relation with what is presented about the chiral super-multiplets in global supersymmetry. One talks about a Kähler potential and a scalar field (+its fermonic chiral counterpart) following a $\sigma$-model like form.

Why is it not possible to add to the super-gravity Lagrangian ${\cal{L}}_{EH} + {\cal{L}}_{RS}$ the Wess-Zumino Lagrangian ${\cal{L}}_{WZ}$ to ${\cal{L}}_{EH} + {\cal{L}}_{RS} + {\cal{L}}_{WZ}$? I already noted that the construction of the energy-momentum stress tensor is difficult or not possible at all as the latter is a result of the variation of the matter-Lagrangian WRT the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ whereas in first-order formulation of supergravity the variation is WRT the vielbein or the connection field.

Of course the  Wess-Zumino Lagrangian ${\cal{L}}_{WZ}$ would have to be made covariant using covariant derivatives. But possibly this is not enough as ${\cal{L}}_{WZ}$ has to be locally supersymmetric invariant for fitting into supergravity. Is this observation correct?

Anyway, it also seems that when the matter fields are added to supergravity it is done in  the most general form (see for instance "the supersymmetry primer") which makes the understanding particularly difficult. Can anybody give an example of how to add matter to supergravity in its simplest form (please not in superspace-formalism), i.e. just one ungauged super-multiplet without any gauge fields and explain  why the given terms would deviate from the Wess-Zumino Lagrangian ${\cal{L}}_{WZ}$?