# The Role of the Kaehler Manifold in Supergravity

Tags: differential-geometry, covariance, supergravity, theory-of-everything

Actually, I already asked a similar question  [Coupling of supergravity to matter](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/772686/)  which has remained unanswered. So this time I will be less general.

In the very interesting paper [arXiv:2212.10044](https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.10044) [hep-th] Simple Supergravity from G. Dall'Agata & Marco Zagermann they show in a very intuitive way how to promote supersymmetry to a local symmetry.  They start from the Lagrangian:

$${{\cal L}_{WZ}} = -\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu \phi^{\ast} - (\bar{\chi}_L\,\not\partial\chi_L + \bar{\chi}_L\, \not\partial\chi_R) \tag{1} $$

and show that (using the Noether procedure) by adding a Lagrangian term (I will simply set the Planck mass $M_P=1$):

$${{\cal L'}} = - (\bar{\psi}_{\mu L} j^\mu_L + \bar{\psi}_{\mu R} j^\mu_R) \tag{11}$$

to the W-Z Lagrangian the whole Lagrangian would be invariant which is achieved by the introduction of the Rarita-Schwinger field $\psi_\mu$ (apart from the variations of the supercurrents which leads to a further extension).

Later on in section 4.1 when Supergravity is coupled to matter fields, in particular to the chiral multiplets, the extended Wess-Zumino Lagrangian is given as ($g_{m\bar{n}} =\partial_m\partial_\bar{n} K$ being the Kaehler metric):

$${{\cal L}_{WZ}} = -g_{m\bar{n}} \left[(\partial_\mu\phi^m)(\partial^\mu \phi^\bar{n})  +\bar{\chi}^m_L\, {\not{\cal D}} \chi^\bar{n}_R   + \bar{\chi}^\bar{n}_R\, {\not{\cal D}} \chi^m_L   \right] + \ldots \tag{91}$$

where the $\ldots$ comprise the terms containing the holomorphic superpotential and higher order terms.

I was now expecting as covariant derivative a derivative according to the principle of minimal coupling $ {{\cal D}}_\mu= \partial_\mu + ig \psi_\mu $, but actually it was given as (apparently the R-S field cannot be introduced so easily as by a minimal coupling):

$${{\cal D}}_\mu\chi^m_L = \partial_{\mu}\chi^m_L + (\partial_\mu \phi^n)\Gamma^m_{nl}\chi^l_L $$

saying that "the derivative ${{\cal D}}$ is covariant with respect to arbitrary holomorphic scalar field reparametrizations and hence contains Christoffel symbols $\Gamma^m_{nl}$ on the scalar manifold."

I.e. it means that it is related with the Kaehler manifold.

My questions:

1. What is a Kaehler manifold and why is it needed, in particular in Supergravity?
2. I have never seen a Kaehler manifold when global supersymmetry is discussed. Why not ? It seems to be a generalization of the simple concept of a chiral multiplet, why is it not introduced when global supersymmetry is discussed?
3. It seems that once matter coupling to Supergravity is discussed there seems to be the attempt of the construction of the most general Lagrangian, i.e. to write down the Lagrangian of the "Theory of Everything" (TOE), which eventually fails as this theory is not renormalizable. Why is there the tendency to be as general as possible although we know it does not fulfill the expectations of a TOE?

In my view it makes the Supergravity matter coupling discussion more complicated
as necessary, in particular in paedagogical texts (my impression: pure Supergravity is rather easy as long as no matter fields are involved). In particular I haven't found a source yet which explains the purpose of a Kaehler manifold in Supergravity.